# Hide object methods from IntelliSense in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

I've created a nice way for my non-tech colleague to control something in C# (classes system with properties and methods), let's call it Domain Specific Language or something like that.

So my non-tech colleague than writes like SOMECLASS. and immediately sees options to choose from in IntelliSense, so let's say he then chooses SOMEPROPERTY so he have like: SOMECLASS.SOMEPROPERTY. he sees another suggestions in IntelliSense and so on...
He just chooses things from what I prepared for him to be choosable.

Buuut, only problem is, that there are these object methods like ToString, GetHashCode, Equals and so on, which I don't want to see in IntelliSense, because it is pointlessly distracting attention from what really is an option to choose from. One has to scan a little longer through those suggestions to really see what he can choose...

Sooo does anybody of you knows some extension for Visual Studio 2022, that would hide these basic object methods from IntelliSense? I will greatly appreciate, if you point me to something like that. Ooor, would something like this be hard to code if I decide to code it myself? I've never created any extensions for Visual Studio, but maybe this task wouldn't be that hard?

EDIT: I found, that this could be done using ReSharper, but that extension is waaay too expensive for me, so I am looking for some other cheaper solution.

Thanks sooo much for any help !!!!

Comment: I‘m afraid there is no option to hide object methods from IntelliSense in Visual Studio. If you wish to implement this in VS, you can try to suggest on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion). If you want to create your own extension you can search the related API from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=visualstudiosdk-2022&term=intellisense)

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer :) When I will have more time, I will maybe code it myself then :D